# What's the asymptotic behavior of ${_2F}_1(-a,n;1-a;z)$ when $a\to 0$?

Tags: limits, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Consider a function $f(a)={_2F}_1(-a,n;1-a;z)$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $0\le a<1$, $z<0$, and ${_2F}_1$ is a Gauss hypergeometric function.

Then what's the asymptotic behavior of $f(a)$ when $a\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: What is $_2F_1(-a,n;1-a;z)$?

Comment: Plotting it for a few values it seems to go to $1$. Mathematica also gives this as the limit.

Comment: I wonder if the people voting to close know what the Pfaff transformation is...

Comment: I did not vote to close, but I think that one of the reason is the way the question is asked, that is, a professor who asks the students to do a task.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Pfaff transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.8.E1), we have

$$f(a)={}_2 F_1\left({{-a,n}\atop{1-a}}\middle|z\right)=(1-z)^{1-n}{}_2 F_1\left({{1,1-a-n}\atop{1-a}}\middle|z\right)$$

and thus

$$\begin{align*}
f(0)&=(1-z)^{1-n}{}_2 F_1\left({{1,1-n}\atop{1}}\middle|z\right)=(1-z)^{1-n}{}_1 F_0\left({{1-n}\atop{}}\middle|z\right)\\
&=(1-z)^{1-n}\left((1-z)^{-(1-n)}\right)=1
\end{align*}$$

where the identical numerator and denominator parameters cancel, and one is left with [an elementary hypergeometric series](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F0/02/0002/) (the binomial series in disguise).